# How to get & set the video format in youtube-dl?

Tags: php, unix, youtube-dl

I want to download **mp3** or any other **audio file** available through **youtube-dl**.

**getaudio.php**

```
<?php
    $youtubeUrl =  $_GET['url'];
    $content = shell_exec("youtube-dl -j $youtubeUrl "); 
    $meta=json_decode($content);  
    $file= $meta->{'_filename'};
    $fileWithoutExtension = explode(".",$file)[0];
    $extension = ".m4a";
    $file = $fileWithoutExtension . $extension;         
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file\"" );
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    passthru("youtube-dl -o - $youtubeUrl");
?>
```

This file downloads the **video file**. Before downloading I need to confirm all the audio formats available. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

By default, `youtube-dl` downloads a YouTube video in `mp4` format.

There is an option to have `youtube-dl` convert the video to an audio file. In their documentation for ["Post Processing Options"](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl#post-processing-options), you can pass in the `-x` option to convert the video file to audio (*this requires `ffmpeg` installed*) and `youtube-dl` will download the "best" format available. If you need a specified format, then you can use the `--audio-format` option.

I doubt `youtube-dl` can confirm all audio formats available before downloading because it still downloads the video in `mp4` format but uses `ffmpeg` to convert it to the specified audio format and in the end removes the `mp4` file.